# GCP VM: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: timed out: unknown

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nvidia

Lately my GCP VM of multiple GPUs throws the following error when I try to run my container:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container ini
t caused: Running hook #1:: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: driver error: timed out: unknown
```

I also noticed, that executing `nvidia-smi` takes more than 30 seconds most of the time.

Specs:

- base image: `nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04`
- nvidia driver: 450.102.04
- zone: europe-west1-b

I've been using this setup for months and never noticed anything alike.

Comment: First check the service status: ```$systemctl status docker``` Try a restart: ```$systemctl restart docker``` And let us know your results also share the Docker version is the issue persists.

Comment: Have you tried updating NVIDIA drivers? What is the output of  `nvidia-container-cli -k -d /dev/tty info` ? I saw somethin similar [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1133) but the output of the command would be a good starting point.

Comment: It might be related with this [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48074282/docker-container-not-starting-giving-oci-runtime-create-failed).

Comment: Are you(@ben0it8) still facing the problem? Was your problem resolved? If yes, can you mention the steps you have taken to solve the problem.